# Glyph spacing in .ttf files

Tags: pdf, glyph, kerning

I want the PDF to store hindi characters. However, there is space between the characters. I want to eliminate this space.

The way I want it to appear: कम
The way it is appearing: क म

The kerning information is supposed to be specified in a either a kern table or a part of the GSUB table. However, the .ttf file that I have (Akshar.ttf) [image: set of parameters displayed in fontdrop.info]

I tried using the site fontdrop.info to retrieve information, however, each glyph there has only a certain number of parameters. I tried to get the spacing for specific pairs of characters using these specified parameters but could not find any proper correlation between the parameters and the space I need to reduce after the printing of each character for the characters to come together.

I however, know that the kerning information has to be present in the .ttf file. However, I have no clue where or in what form. In fact, it is very ambiguous right now on what parameters like "advance width" and "xmax value" mean as intuitively, the former is supposed to be greater than the larger; and yet, that is not the case.

Please suggest me where in the .ttf or the .ttx or fontdrop.info I can find the information about what amount of units of space I need to subtract for a particular glyph in order for the hindi characters to appear together.

Comment: Please clarify: How is the PDF file being created? Are you programmatically generating a PDF file (yourself or using some library) and determining the placement of each glyph (so you want to be sure what metric data in the font will be needed to do that correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

The kerning information is stored either in kern table (old style) or in GPOS (not GSUB) table.

FontDrop does not parse and display the GPOS table, it displays only the kern table.

The metrics you asked about are detailed in the OpenType specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/